# Syscall from inline asm in x86_64 Linux?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

Why does this print garbage instead of exiting my program gracefully? I use system calls this way on BSD, and I wonder what would I need to make it work in Linux.

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    __asm ("movq $1,%rax; movq $0,%rdi; syscall"); /* exit(0) ? */
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Why does this print garbage instead of exiting my program gracefully?

Per [CESA-2009-001](http://scary.beasts.org/security/CESA-2009-001.html), "Syscall 1 is exit on i386 but write on x86_64".

> what would I need to make it work in Linux

Use the syscall ordinals from the current [unistd_64.h](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-2.6-stable.git;a=blob;f=arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_64.h)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you! this is it. I don't know why they had to change it though. So BSD uses the traditional numbers while Linux 64 has changed them. This means I cannot reuse my code though :(

Comment: @jbcreix, out of curiosity *why* would you do this instead of using the portable calls `exit()` and `write()`? Isn't this just asking for trouble?

Comment: The portable calls need linking to glibc or other C libraries. This way I can implement only the functions I need the way I need and independent from the OS. Of course static linking would achieve a similar result, but then there are licensing issues with GPL code.

Comment: @jbcreix It looks like they changed them to conform to some common ABI. The definitions for i386 were in "entry.S", for x64 it's "unistd_64.h".
@RBerteig Sometimes one just needs a challenge. Like writing an executable without linking to anything! It can also be a useful technique in security applications and exploit code.

Answer (score 3):

Syscall 1 is exit on i386 but write on x86-64 I believe.

EDIT: this seems inaccurate:
According to the web, which does not seem to have too much information about x86-64 Linux assembly this seems to be the expected register setup before the syscall instruction.

```
 rax  system call number
 rbx  arg0
 rcx  return address from syscall
 rdx  arg2
 rsi  arg3
 rdi  arg4
 r8   arg5
 r9   arg1    (expected by gcc in %rcx)
 r10-r15  should be saved/restored by C code
 rbp  dito What is dito??
```

Comment: Hmm, is this register information wrong? Is rdi for arg1 as OP suggests?

Comment: Yes. The order is rdi,rsi,rdx,... like in regular functions with the syscall number going to rax. This might have been true for the first Linux x86_64 versions that maybe copied the i386 abi, but I don't know for sure. Anyways in this case a bad value for arg1, etc. couldn't have possibly caused the problem as exit will always succeed and terminate the process.

Comment: Yes, I was pretty sure the main issue was due to it using NR_write instead of NR_exit, but thought that the argument might be off also!