# Good references for the syscalls

Tags: linux, assembly, reference, nasm

I need some reference but a good one, possibly with some nice examples. I need it because I am starting to write code in assembly using the NASM assembler. I have this reference:

http://bluemaster.iu.hio.no/edu/dark/lin-asm/syscalls.html

which is quite nice and useful, but it's got a lot of limitations because it doesn't explain the fields in the other registers. For example, if I am using the write syscall, I know I should put 1 in the EAX register, and the ECX is probably a pointer to the string, but what about EBX and EDX? I would like that to be explained too, that EBX determines the input (0 for stdin, 1 for something else etc.) and EDX is the length of the string to be entered, etc. etc. I hope you understood me what I want, I couldn't find any such materials so that's why I am writing here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

The standard programming language in Linux is C. Because of that, the best descriptions of the system calls will show them as C functions to be called. Given their description as a C function and a knowledge of how to map them to the actual system call in assembly, you will be able to use any system call you want easily.

First, you need a reference for all the system calls as they would appear to a C programmer. The best one I know of is the [Linux man-pages project](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/), in particular the [system calls](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/dir_section_2.html) section.

Let's take the [`write`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/write.2.html) system call as an example, since it is the one in your question. As you can see, the first parameter is a signed integer, which is usually a file descriptor returned by the `open` syscall. These file descriptors could also have been inherited from your parent process, as usually happens for the first three file descriptors (0=stdin, 1=stdout, 2=stderr). The second parameter is a pointer to a buffer, and the third parameter is the buffer's size (as an unsigned integer). Finally, the function returns a signed integer, which is the number of bytes written, or a negative number for an error.

Now, how to map this to the actual system call? There are many ways to do a system call on 32-bit x86 (which is probably what you are using, based on your register names); be careful that it is completely different on 64-bit x86 (be sure you are assembling in 32-bit mode and linking a 32-bit executable; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724141/linux-write-sys-call-using-string-on-stack) for an example of how things can go wrong otherwise). The oldest, simplest and slowest of them in the 32-bit x86 is the `int $0x80` method.

For the `int $0x80` method, you put the system call number in `%eax`, and the parameters in `%ebx`, `%ecx`, `%edx`, `%esi`, `%edi`, and `%ebp`, in that order. Then you call `int $0x80`, and the return value from the system call is on `%eax`. Note that this return value is *different* from what the reference says; the reference shows how the C library will return it, but the system call returns `-errno` on error (for instance `-EINVAL`). The C library will move this to `errno` and return `-1` in that case. See [syscalls(2)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [intro(2)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/intro.2.html) for more detail.

So, in the `write` example, you would put the `write` system call number in `%eax`, the first parameter (file descriptor number) in `%ebx`, the second parameter (pointer to the string) in `%ecx`, and the third parameter (length of the string) in `%edx`. The system call will return in `%eax` either the number of bytes written, or the error number negated (if the return value is between -1 and -4095, it is a negated error number).

Finally, how do you find the system call numbers? They can be found at `/usr/include/linux/unistd.h`. On my system, this just includes `/usr/include/asm/unistd.h`, which finally includes `/usr/include/asm/unistd_32.h`, so the numbers are there (for `write`, you can see `__NR_write` is `4`). The same goes for the error numbers, which come from `/usr/include/linux/errno.h` (on my system, after chasing the inclusion chain I find the first ones at `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h` and the rest at `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h`). For the system calls which use other constants or structures, their documentation tells which headers you should look at to find the corresponding definitions.

---

Now, as I said, `int $0x80` is the oldest and slowest method. Newer processors have special system call instructions which are faster. To use them, the kernel makes available a virtual dynamic shared object (the `vDSO`; it is like a shared library, but in memory only) with a function you can call to do a system call using the best method available for your hardware. It also makes available special functions to get the current time without even having to do a system call, and a few other things. Of course, it is a bit harder to use if you are not using a dynamic linker.

There is also another older method, the `vsyscall`, which is similar to the `vDSO` but uses a single page at a fixed address. This method is deprecated, will result in warnings on the system log if you are using recent kernels, can be disabled on boot on even more recent kernels, and might be removed in the future. Do not use it.

Comment: This is one of the best answers I have ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

If you download that web page (like it suggests in the second paragraph) and download the kernel sources, you can click the links in the "Source" column, and go directly to the source file that implements the system calls.  You can read their C signatures to see what each parameter is used for.

If you're just looking for a quick reference, each of those system calls has a C library interface with the same name minus the `sys_`.  So, for example, you could check out [`man 2 lseek`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/lseek.2.html) to get the information about the parameters for`sys_lseek`:

```
off_t lseek(int fd, off_t offset, int whence);
```

where, as you can see, the parameters match the ones from your HTML table:

```
%ebx           %ecx    %edx
unsigned int   off_t   unsigned int
```

Comment: Of course, even if you search for each one in google or any source-code search enginge for it's implementation, you can find direct examples how they are used - which I did. The point of my post is to skip the searching and analyzing with some nice cheat-sheet. Thanks.