# Learning assembly - echo program name

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I am trying to write a simple program in assembly that will write out the name of the program. Using gdb to debug, I've determined that the call to sys_write is returning -14 (EFAULT).  I've also been able to verify that my strlen function is working correctly.  It seems like there is some sort of memory access issue, but I don't understand what could be wrong given that strlen is accessing the same memory and working fine.  What is going wrong?

Thanks!

The full code:

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, [rsp+8]
    push rax
    call strlen
    add rsp, 8

    mov rdx, rax ; bytes to write
    mov rax, 4 ; sys_write
    mov rbx, 1 ; stdout
    mov rcx, [rsp+8] ; addr of string
    int 0x80

    ; exit
    mov rax, 1
    mov rbx, 0
    int 0x80

strlen:
    mov rax, 0
    mov rbx, [rsp+8]
strlen_loop:
    cmp byte [rbx+rax], 0
    je strlen_end
    inc rax
    jmp strlen_loop
strlen_end:
    ret ; len in rax
```

Comment: tried stepping through this line-by-line in a debugger to verify that the args to sys_write are correct?

Comment: Yes, I stopped execution at the first int 0x80 and verified that all  the arguments are correct.  And I used x/s $rcx in gdb to make sure that there is actually a string where I think there should be one.

Comment: On x86_64 `int $0x80` isn't used for syscall (and the syscall numbers have changed), see one of the many previous discussions e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204026/syscall-from-inline-asm-in-x86-64-linux

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I wrote in a comment, x86_64 uses a different method for syscalls than 32-bit linux. In particular `int $0x80` is no longer the way to do it (though it might semi-work if you have the 32-bit libraries installed....). See for instance this [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204026/syscall-from-inline-asm-in-x86-64-linux).

Where on 32-bit x86 you would do:

```
mov eax, SYSCALL_NUMBER
mov ebx, first_param
mov ecx, second_param
mov edx, third_param
int 0x80
```

You should do the following on x86_64:

```
mov rax, SYSCALL_NUMBER_64 ; This is usually different from the 32-bit version!
mov rdi, first_param
mov rsi, second_param
mov rdx, third_param
syscall
```

To print the program name, change your program to the following and it should work. For anyone else interested in how the program environment looks on startup, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683144/linux-64-command-line-parameters-in-assembly).

```
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov rax, [rsp+8]
    push rax
    call strlen
    add rsp, 8

    mov rdi, 1 ; fd = stdout
    mov rsi, [rsp+8] ; buf = addr to string
    mov rdx, rax ; count = strlen(string)
    mov rax, 1 ; write
    syscall

    mov rdi, 0 ; status = 0
    mov rax, 60 ; exit
    syscall

strlen:
    mov rax, 0
    mov rbx, [rsp+8]
strlen_loop:
    cmp byte [rbx+rax], 0
    je strlen_end
    inc rax
    jmp strlen_loop
strlen_end:
    ret ; len in rax
```

Compiled using:

```
nasm -g -f elf64 -o sc.o sc.asm
gcc -nostartfiles -o sc sc.o
```

Answer (score 0):

You add rsp with 8 at the beginning causing the `sys_write` call to get another string than your strlen function. The `strlen` does not alter the stack and the pushed `rax` is not used later? Why don't you drop the `push rax` and `add rsp, 8` statements and see how that works our for you?

Comment: the `add rsp,8` is stack cleanup for the `__cdecl` call to `strlen` where the "pushed rax" is used...