# How to compile this asm code under linux with nasm and gcc?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86, nasm

I have the following source snippet from a book that I'm reading now. So I created an asm file and typed exactly. Then used nasm command (`nasm -f elf test.asm`) then tried to compile into an executable file by using `gcc` (`gcc test.o -o test`) then I get the following error.

**Error:**

> ld: warning: ignoring file test.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)

**Source code:**

```
[BITS 16]

[SECTION .text]

START:
    mov dx, eatmsg
    mov ah, 9
    int 21H

    mov ax, 04C00H
    int 21H

[SECTION .data]

eatmsg  db "Eat at Joe's!", 13, 10, "$"
```

I guess the source code is not compatible with current generation of CPUs (the book is old...).

How do I fix this source code to run under x86_64 CPUs ?

Comment: change to `[BITS 64]` ? But there are other problems as well, where did you set the entry point ?

Comment: @Moon: `int 21h` is the interface for 16-bit DOS, 32-bit linux uses `int 80h` and x86_64 uses `syscall` (for a quick example see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006926/learning-assembly-echo-program-name/7009032#7009032)) or search SO for one of the many other threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to continue using that old book to learn the basics (which is just fine, nothing wrong with learning the basics/old way before moving on to modern OS), you can run it in DOSBox, or a FreeDOS VM.

Comment: // Thank you for the advice. Yes..that's my aim. I just can't leanr modern assembly language concepts without understanding why we're using current memory models...

Answer (score 1):

That's a 16 bits code, it was made to create pure binary code and not executables. You cannot run it on modern OSs like Linux without heavy modifications. And btw, that's an MS-DOS assembly, which will not work for Linux anyway (using int 21h which are MS-DOS services).

If you want to learn assembly, I suggest getting a more modern book, or setting up a virtual machine in which to learn with your book (although learning 16-bits assembly is really not useful nowadays).

Answer (score 1):

First of all the code contains interrupts which will work in real mode only and in DOS (`int 21h` with values in regs), and linux works in protected mode, you cannot call these interrupts directly.

Next the code is 16 bit code, to make it a 64 bit code you need `[BITS 64]`

Third you have no entry point to the code. To make one you can write a main function in C and then call the starting label as a function in the assembly code.

Have a look at this thing: [PC Assembly Language by Paul A. Carter](http://www.scribd.com/doc/6900/PC-Assembly-Tutorial)

Comment: Interrupts can be used in protected mode as well. Check how Linux uses INT 0x80 for system calls (or at least it used it back on 2.4 kernels ^^)

Comment: @m0skit0: they cannot be called directly, and also the `int 21h` is DOS interrupts, and the functions which is used will be only available in DOS. (`ah = 09h` with `ds:dx = address of char string` and `int 21h` will print the char string ($ terminated) ).

Comment: Yes they can be called directly, don't be stubborn :P http://bluemaster.iu.hio.no/edu/dark/lin-asm/syscalls.html

Comment: And also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_descriptor_table#Protected_mode. And I know 21h is MSDOS service, as I stated on my answer.

Comment: i know , they can be called, but in the above code in question, will simply not work.