# How to use cmp to compare two literals

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

My goal is to create a high/low game where my computer does a simple calculation of half way between the last two possible numbers it could be. It asks, "Am I getting warmer?" The thing I need to get it going (and I don't know if this is nasm specific or something) is knowledge of why the `cmp` instruction isn't working. I've tried several answers and they do not work.

I tried using

`mov r8w, 'Y'`

I have also tried

`mov r8w, 59h`

Both to compare to the word register `r8w`. I want to know where in my code I'm skipping the logic. Here's the code.

```
.loop:

        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, hot_cold
        mov rdx, w_len
        syscall

        mov r9w, 0
        mov rax, 0              ; setup for input
        mov rbx, 0              ;
        mov rdi, 2              ;
        mov si, r9w             ; collect input
        syscall                 ; init collection

        mov r8w, 0              ;
        mov r8w, 'Y'            ; 59h
        cmp r9w, r8w            ; compare to Y
        jne .hop_no             ; compare fail, try N
        jmp _for_y              ; compare success, change numbers
        ;syscall
        jmp .loop               ; loop on successful Y

.hop_no:
        mov r8w, 0
        mov r8w, 'N'            ;4Eh
        cmp r8w, r9w            ; compare to N
        jne _exit               ; compare fail, exit
        call _for_n             ; compare success change numbers
        ;syscall                                                                                                                                                                                                           
        jmp .loop
```

Comment: @PeterCordes Okay, so the (strace is awesome) EFAULT is happening. I says bad address. What can I do to clear that variable?

Comment: You can read [How to read input from STDIN in x86\_64 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9646796) which I linked in my answer.

Comment: If the instruction set can't do something in one instruction, then use two or more instructions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two *literals*?  As in assemble-time-constant values like `1234` or `'Y'`?  That's normally useless because you can just figure out the result yourself, or use `%if` to let the assembler do it at assemble time.  i.e. optimize away the cmp instead of writing instructions that set and read FLAGS.

But if you insist, `cmp` can take at most one immediate operand, so `mov`-immediate the other constant number to a register first.

```
    mov  eax, 'Y'
    cmp  AL, 'Y'
```

This sets flags:

- ZF=1 because 'Y' - 'Y' = 0
- CF=OF=0 because no borrow, and no signed overflow
- SF=0

(Also PF and AF are written.)

---

re: your actual code that tries to compare a runtime variable I/O result with an integer literal constant `'Y'`

It looks like you think you can `read` bytes into a register.  This is not the case.  There is no system-call equivalent to `getchar`.  `mov si, r9w` copies the contents (leaving the high 6 bytes of RSI unmodified), not setting SI = the address of R9W.  **Registers do not have addresses**.

Read into a buffer (e.g. on the stack) and then load that into a register.  [How to read input from STDIN in x86_64 assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646796/how-to-read-input-from-stdin-in-x86-64-assembly)  Or use `cmp` with a memory operand.

Use `strace ./my_program` to see what system calls you're making and what error code or success they return.

The 64-bit calling convention doesn't pass an arg in RBX.  I think `mov rbx, 0` is a typo for `mov edx, 2`.  (You seem to have your length and FD args mixed up, too.)  You want RDI=fd=0, RDX=length=2.  (Or more, in case the user types a longer line).

RSI needs to point to memory for `read(int fd, void *buf, size_t len)`.  You have the high 6 bytes of RSI set from the address of `hot_cold`, but the low 2 bytes set to zero from copying `r9w` for no apparent reason.  This might make it return `-EFAULT`, or you might be just writing somewhere else in your `.data` section.

Comment: Why am I just looping now? I did all you said, but It doesn't go do anything. Do you want me to update the code?